# C++ Can I print the content of 1 or 2 dim array using Visual Studio's Command window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, command-window

C++ Can I print the content of 1 or 2 dim array using Visual Studio's Command window? I guess it comes down to whether a "command window" support some kind of loop and print (?) syntax or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual studio command window is used to enter commands to the development environment, not for code execution. For example you could type 'open' so that VS shows the Open Dialog.